# Set object's values in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I would like to store User Data as a single object in Local Storage.

Here is the code and below it the problem description:

```
const firstName = document.getElementById('firstname');
const lastName = document.getElementById('lastname');
const address = document.getElementById('address');
const city = document.getElementById('city');
const postCode = document.getElementById('postcode');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const checkBox = document.getElementById('check-remember');
const message = document.getElementById('message');

// define userData object 

let userData = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    address: '',
    city: '',
    postCode: '',
    email: '',
    checkBox: '',
    message: ''
};

// set this object as string in the LS 

localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));

// parse it to native JS data and store it in new var

let userDataNative = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));

// add event listeners to form's input fields: 

firstName.addEventListener('keyup', setFirstName);
lastName.addEventListener('keyup', setLastName);
address.addEventListener('keyup', setAddress);
city.addEventListener('keyup', setCity);
postCode.addEventListener('keyup', setPostCode);
email.addEventListener('keyup', setEmail);
message.addEventListener('keyup', setUserMessage);

// set actual input values as userData object's value for each key

function setFirstName(event) {
    userData.firstName = event.target.value;
}
function setLastName(event) {
    userData.lastName = event.target.value;
}
function setAddress(event) {
    userData.address = event.target.value;
}
function setCity(event){
    userData.city = event.target.value;
}
function setPostCode(event){
    userData.postCode = event.target.value;    
}
function setEmail(event){
    userData.email = event.target.value;
}
function setUserMessage(event){
    userData.message = event.target.value;
}
```

The Problem: the userData object in Local Storage is not updated. When I enter some text in the input fields on the page and then log userData I do get an object with the right keys and the actual values in the console - BUT the userData object in Local Storage stays empty.

Can you help? What am I missing here?

Many thanks, all help much appreciated.

Comment: `localStorage` holds a string, not a live reference. After changing your object in any of the event listeners, you will need to call `localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));` again.

Comment: In the console of chrome, running the part of object definition and the set and getItem of localStorage, everything works fine. The LocalStorage have a size limitation https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/#toc-desktop. Could it be the case? Maybe some property like message....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're assuming `userData` is a reference to `localStorage`, but it is not. Since `localStorage` is a string and you have to parse it to a javascript object, there is no such relationship. This means that, to re-save the information to `localStorage`, you need to execute the following code again.

```
localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));
```

Comment: Thanks! I put this line of code inside every single event handler function. Now, When I type stuff into the form fields, they did indeed update the userData object in locaStorage. BUT: when I refresh the page, they all disappear and the values of the userData object in local storage default back to empty strings... do you know why that might happen? Many thanks indeed.